# Stored Procedure to display different COUNT in SELECT clause

Tags: asp.net, .net, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I've been trying for hours to figure something out and I haven't come up with a suitable solution.

I have a table called `EmailTasks` in SQL Server:

```
 Id  | HasFailed | CreateDate
 19  |   1       |  10/11/2011
 29  |   0       |  09/11/2011
 15  |   1       |  14/12/2011
```

I would like to build a store procedure that accepts two parameters: `@beginDate`, `@endDate`.

It selects the relevant records from the table `EmailTasks` (i.e `CreateDate` between  `@beginDate` and `@endDate`)and returns the following table with 3 columns:

1. `TotalEmails`: The total number of emails,
2. `Failed`: The number of emails that failed (hasFailed = 1),
3. `Suceess`: The number of emails that succeeded (hasFailed = 0).

For example: `sp_GetEmailTemplateStatistics('08/11/2011', '11/11/2011')` will return:

```
TotalEmails | Failed | Suceess
     2      |  1     |  1
```

**Please Notice**: The record with `Id=15` is not counted because the `CreateDate` (14/12/2011) is bigger than the parameter `@endDate`.

Answer (score 9):

You can always do something like:

```
select 
  (select count(*) from EmailTasks 
    where CreateDate between @beginDate and @endDate)
    as TotalEmails,
  (select count(*) from EmailTasks 
    where CreateDate between @beginDate and @endDate 
      and HasFailed = 1)
    as Failed,
  (select count(*) from EmailTasks 
    where CreateDate between @beginDate and @endDate 
      and HasFailed = 0)
    as Suceess
```

This will return correct values, but will execute thrice against the table, and it's conditions are repeated three times, so there is a possibility of a paste mistake if the logic is modified.

If HasFailed will always be 0 or 1 (a `bit` field), you can do this more clever but less clear solution:

```
  select 
    count(*) as TotalEmails, 
    sum(cast(HasFailed as int)) as Failed, 
    sum(1-cast(HasFailed as int)) as Suceess
  from EmailTasks 
    where CreateDate between @beginDate and @endDate
```

- the casting is necessary because the `sum` operator is invalid on `bit` fields, as pointed by Martin Smith

Comment: "(a bit field)" - or an integer field acting as a flag.

Comment: @MarkBannister: I mean, if there is some mechanism (whatever it is) that guarantees that there won't be a loose 2 somewhere :)

Comment: If it is a `bit` you will need to cast to `int` to aggregate it.

Comment: looks like some () are missing to compile the stored proc properly.

Comment: I don't think the last solution is less clear, it's what I'd go for.  But with one slight optimisation:  `COUNT(*) - sum(cast(HasFailed as int)) AS Success` - This avoids a new aggregation of a calculation by allowing the optimiser to re-use the values from the two other fields.

Comment: remember that you collect data via expressions - could result in null all over - check if any rows qualify at all ...
sum,count will always reduce to zero

Answer (score 1):

Try this SQL

```
select count(*) as TotalEmails, sum(HasFailed) as Failed, sum(1-HasFailed) as Success
 from EmailTasks where CreateDate between @beginDate and @endDate
```

Comment: Fine except for the comment Martin Smith made 31 minutes before your answer - You can't SUM() a BIT without CASTing it to an INT or other type.